# Mysql view doesn't work

Tags: mysql, view

I have created a test table with this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `zprueba` (
`a` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`b` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`a`),
INDEX `b` (`b`)
)
COLLATE='utf32_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Step 2: I insert 2 rows:

```
INSERT INTO `zprueba` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (1, 'N');
INSERT INTO `zprueba` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (2, 'S');
```

Step 3: I've created a view

```
create view zprueba2 as select a,b from zprueba where b='S'
```

When I call this query, I obtain 1 row:

```
select a,b from zprueba where b='S'
```

But when I call:

```
select a,b from zprueba2
```

I obtain 0 rows.

Anybody could help me with this strange behaviour?

Best regards
Raúl.

Answer (score 0):

No; I cannot repliacte this behaviour...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS zprueba;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS zprueba2;


CREATE TABLE `zprueba` (
`a` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`b` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`a`),
INDEX `b` (`b`)
);

INSERT INTO `zprueba` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (1, 'N');
INSERT INTO `zprueba` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (2, 'S');

create view zprueba2 as select a,b from zprueba where b='S';

select a,b from zprueba2 where b='S';
+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 2 | S |
+---+---+

select a,b from zprueba2;
+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 2 | S |
+---+---+
```